# Quasar Grid Left Align Items In Last Row

Tags: flexbox, alignment, quasar-framework

Is there a trick to centering the items in a grid while keeping the last row left-aligned in Quasar? See my problem below:[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
<div class="row justify-start">
    <div class="col" v-for="item in listB" :key="item.id">
    ...
    </div
</div>
```

or if you want to keep some centered and the last ones aligned to the left, then you must separate them into 2 lists (the centered ones and the ones on the left

```
<div class="row justify-center">
    <div class="col" v-for="item in listA" :key="item.id">
    ...
    </div
</div>
<div class="row justify-start">
    <div class="col" v-for="item in listB" :key="item.id">
    ...
    </div
</div>
```